# Could not locate the assembly when using absolute path

Tags: c#, msbuild, rider

I'm trying to add an assembly reference to my project in Rider, and when doing so, I can normally navigate to the desired folder and select the .dll. The selected .dll immediately appears under assemblies, despite having a warning sign next to it (hovering over it yields no extra information). When trying to build, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2127, 5): [MSB3245] Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

The same happens if I try to build the project from terminal using either xbuild or msbuild. If it makes any difference, I'm using Linux.

Comment: Does your project file itself show you the path you're expecting for that dll if you examine it manually?

Comment: yes, it does however use backslashes instead of normal slashes, but the path checks out. I've tried changing the slashes to unix path and the result was the same